# How to specify JedisConnectionFactory instance for RedisHttpSessionConfiguration initialization

Tags: java, spring, redis

I have a problem exactly the same that described at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/438, where I tried to autowire a specific JedisConnectionFactory to RedisHttpSessionConfiguration. But it failed to create the bean with NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException. The detailed error message is like this,

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: jedisConnectionFactory,jedisConnectionFactory4C

Here is what I put for RedisHttpSessionConfiguraiton in applicationContext.xml,

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration">
    <property name="maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds" value="600"></property>
```

and below are the connection factories.

```
<!-- caching redis-->
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory4C" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${redis.host}" /> 
    <property name="password" value="${redis.passwd}" /> 
    <property name="port" value="${redis.port}" />
    <property name="database" value="${redis.cacheddb}" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="poolConfig"/>
</bean>
```

The question raised in the github link seems got an answer, but I was not able to figure out the exact fix.

Comment: somehow it lost the lines of one connection factory. Add here,

         
 <!-- message redis-->
 <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
     <property name="hostName" value="${redis.host}" /> 
     <property name="password" value="${redis.passwd}" /> 
     <property name="port" value="${redis.port}" />
     <property name="database" value="${redis.msgdb}" />
     <property name="poolConfig" ref="poolConfig"/>
 </bean>

Answer (score 0):

All right, I probably found an answer from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/448. It does work. Anyone has a better solution, please feel free to add up. Thanks.

Comment: Does it really work? I think overrides all other possible beans might use that class